# Implementing Dead Zone for the touch screen in Android

Tags: java, android, touch, processing, multi-touch

I need to implement a sort of Dead Zone for the touch screen in my APK so the activity doesn't receive any touch events from those zones.
It seems not to be trivial as soon as multi-touch events are linked to the first touch down.

Suppose I have a layout with two side-by-side views and want to ignore all the touch activity in the right view ("dead" view is untouchable).

For the single touch it's trivial.

But for the multi-touch the first touch decides everything:

1. If the first one is in the "dead" view I have no events at all.
2. If the first one is in the "life" view and the second is in the "dead" view I receive multi-touch event ACTION_POINTER_DOWN_2.

Currently I have to receive all the events in raw stream and translate it into another stream of events according to my "dead zone" rules.

But the question is: do we have any kind of useful API to restrict the touch screen event processing to the areas we only need?

P.S. I need all this to filter accidental touches near the screen sides when playing games.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want two layout, a live and a dead one, you should add your own `View.OnTouchListener` to each of them.

I've made an example, here is the activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
TextView text;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout linearLayoutDead = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dead);
    linearLayoutDead.setOnTouchListener(onTouchDeadListener);
    LinearLayout linearLayoutLive = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.live);
    linearLayoutLive.setOnTouchListener(onTouchLiveListener);

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
}

private View.OnTouchListener onTouchDeadListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        text.setText(motionEvent.toString());
        return false;
    }

};

private View.OnTouchListener onTouchLiveListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        text.setText(motionEvent.toString());
        return true;
    }

};
```

}

And the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/live"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/background_floating_material_dark">
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/dead"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</LinearLayout>
```

We override the `OnTouch` method and you'll see that, when we make a single or multi touch on the "dead zone" we get an initial response but nothing further.
But what's for the case when we make a first touch in the "live zone" and the second on the dead one?

For this case you should add a new condition to your `OnTouch` method, something like this:

```
private View.OnTouchListener onTouchLiveListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if(motionEvent.getPointerCount()>1){
            if(motionEvent.getY(1) > someNumber){
                //Case when we touch the dead zone, TODO do some ...
            }
        }
        text.setText(motionEvent.toString());
        return true;
    }

};
```

So in this particular case we could check when the touch happen under the "live zone" and simply ignore it or achieve any behavior that we want.

Hope this could be helpful.
Regards
Jose

Comment: Sorry It happened to be my early attempts with Android. I'm no more associated with that project (for almost two years actually). i remember I implemented a sort of the same solution. My touch screen processing filtered off-zone taps and moves removing extra coordinates. At the ent I succeeded to filter what they want ed but the project itself had been finished long time ago.